# mysql cli client, keep session between multiple commands

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$ mysql -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK"
$ ./do-something.sh
$ mysql -e "UNLOCK TABLES"
```

`so-something.sh` script should be unable to write to database.

Is that possible using bash, or I need python or something like that? Problem is that lock is removed when session is lost, can I run 2 commands with same session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the shell script from the MySQL client using the [`system`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) command. So you can write something like this:

```
$ mysql -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; system ./do-something.sh; UNLOCK TABLES;"
```